# Word-Embeddings compression for deep learning models

Tags: compression, word-embedding

Can anyone suggest any techniques/concepts to compress word-embedding like Glove 300d?
As it increases the size of model.

Answer (score 0):

A decent option to go through where deep com-positional code learning neural network is helpful to reduce word embedding size drastically.
This [github link](https://github.com/rsharmapty/neuralcompressor) will help you and give more insights . it is quite beneficial in Sentimental Analysis tasks. 
Need to test on more different NLP tasks.